# How to add a dynamic value for ordinal #4 in Lookup Function?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I've got 2 Data Extensions. Let's call them A and B

In my Journey, I can only easily include the attributes from the Sendable Data Extension (A) that I'm using to trigger the Journey.

However, I need to include a specific value from the Sendable Data Extension (B) in every unique email that gets triggered by Sendable Data Extension (A).

I've tried using the Lookup function but can't figure how to include a **dynamic value** to pull into ordinal 4. In the example provided in the documentation, they have a hardcoded value but do not point to how to include a dynamic variable here.

User flow

1. Customer X enters Journey triggered by Sendable Data Extension (A)
2. Salesforce function needed to look into a specific column in Sendable Data Extension (B) by referencing Customer X's email address (this email address is also available in Data Extension (B) as a cross-reference )
3. Value gets populated in the email, email gets sent to Customer Y

This is what I have so far, but it isn't working:

```
%%=Lookup('CustomerAttributes','referral_link','email_address','referrer_email'=%%
```

- CustomerAttributes = Name of data extension from which to return the specified value
- referral_link = Name of column from which to return a value
- email_address = Name of column used to identify row containing lookup value
- referrer_email = Value to match string against

Comment: Very well put together question! I don't know a thing about Marketing Cloud, just some minor changes to improve visibility. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just use a DE field or a [system personalization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) value in the ordinal. So it would be like

`%%=Lookup('CustomerAttributes','referral_link','email_address',emailaddr_)=%%`

Or if you field in your sending DE is called email

`%%=Lookup('CustomerAttributes','referral_link','email_address',email)=%%`

This covered in more detail in '[Ampscript 201](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript201.htm)'

But this part of your question:

> Value gets populated in the email, email gets sent to Customer Y

The journey will only send email to the contact that entered the journey

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!